# How to execute newly developed maven plugin in the same project

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I have a maven project with a couple of child modules. One is a new maven plugin. Another one is a test module where I want to run my newly developed plugin to ensure that it works fine.

In the test module I do a normal reference to my plugin: `build > plugins > plugin > <definition of my plugin>`. And then if I executed `mvn clean test` it works fine. The plugin is being compiled and later, in the next module it is executed.

But there are a couple of problems with this setup:

1. When I do `mvn clean` execution fails with `plugin cannot be resolved` as the second module does not have even compiled version of the plugin.
2. In IDE (Intellij IDEA) reimport of maven modules fails with the same problem.

I do not want to do `mvn install` to have it locally so the dependencies are resolved as I do changes quite frequently and do not want to reinstall it every time.

I do not want to write integration tests instead of running the plugin directly as I want a realistic test and moreover, the plugin setup is quite tricky and would be hard to replicate that in a test.

I thought that I could use `systemPath` to reference the plugin but I am not sure if that will work and how to set it up.